# Do I have to place second "the" in "... girl with ... long hair is his girlfriend"?

Tags: definite-article

My sentence is :

> ... girl with ... long hair is his girlfriend.

I know the first blank should be "the" but the second blank, I didn't need to put anything but my teacher said it should be "the". So, why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are grammatical and idiomatic:

> The girl with long hair is his girlfriend.
>
> The girl with the long hair is his girlfriend.

"The girl with long hair" is presented as a single gestalt entity. The second one, "*the* girl with *the* long hair..." draws attention to the length of the hair as a separate phenomenon (on which the listener's attention should be placed), a twofold subject-image, not a gestalt. A visual metaphor for this two-ness might be a photograph with a magnified inset.

[image]